# JQUERY fadeOut Maque

Tags: jquery

```
function UYARIAYAR(kevent,RENGa){
$('marquee').fadeOut(10);
$('.olays').html(kevent).css({"color":RENGa}).fadeIn(100).animate({opacity: 1}, 2200,function(){ 
$(this).animate({opacity: 0.8}, 1800,function(){
$(this).animate({pacity: 0.6}, 800,function(){
$(this).animate({opacity: 0.4}, 800,function() { 
$(this).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 800).css({"color":"#600"}).fadeOut(1);
})})})})
setTimeout('$("marquee").fadeIn().start();',8000);
}

function uyari(tur,mesaj){
var mesajimiz = null;
var font_renk = null;
    switch($.trim(tur)){
    case 'hata' : mesajimiz = 'Yaptıgınız İşlemde Hata Meydana Geldi'; font_renk='red'; break;
    default  : mesajimiz = 'Yaptıgınız İşlem Okey Canım'; font_renk='green'; break;
        }
    UYARIAYAR(mesajimiz,font_renk)
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    uyari('hata',null);
});
```

Everythings are working good
bu when MARQUEE Dom coming back it is not starting stopping not scrolling..

Comment: ..marquee? seriously? in 2012??

Answer (score 0):

Try using stop() in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

The `<marquee>` tag is **not** standard html ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element)), and as such its behavior is very likely to change on different platforms, so it's not that strange that jQuery fails when fading it out.

I'd recommend **not** using it nor using any scrolling animation at all, as such animations are proven to be very distracting and usually quite ugly.

Another suggestion: I'd replace this code:

```
setTimeout('$("marquee").fadeIn().start();',8000);
```

with this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("marquee").fadeIn();
}, 8000);
```

(it does the exact same thing, but it's way more readable and you don't have to double-quote stuff).

**EDIT:**

`$( ... ).fadeIn().start()` is not a function -- just use `$( ... ).fadeIn()`.